# Proof of definitions of Herbrand Model

Tags: first-order-logic

I've struggle to understand the proofs of definitions of the Herbrand Model. I'm referring to the textbook first-order logic and automated theorem proving by Melvin Fitting, 2nd.

Proposition: $M = \langle D, I\rangle$ is a Herbrand Model for the language $L$.  For any term $t$ of $L$, not necessarily closed, $t^{I,A} = (tA)^I$

The proof is: Suppose $t$ is variable $v$. Then $t^{I,A} = v^{I,A} = v^A$, and  $(tA)^I = (vA)^I = vA$ since $I$ is the identity on closed term. Finally $v^A = vA$

I understand why $(vA)^I = vA$, because if i used $A$ as a substition, the term has no free variables and by definition i can write $t^I=t$ if the term is closed. But i do not understand why $v^{I,A} = v^A$ and why $v^A = vA$ follows from this.
I understand the proof if $t$ is a constant.

I would be very thankful, if anyone can help me to understand this proof .

Comment: Can you explain the notation? What is $A$?

Comment: $A$ is an assignement in Model $M$, $v^A$ means, that A is used as an assignment. $vA$ means, that $A$ is used as a substitution.
An assignment in a model   M=⟨D,I⟩ is a mapping $A$ from the set of
variables to the set $D$.

A substitution is a mapping a : $V  \longrightarrow T$ from the set of variables $V$ to
the set of terms $T$.

Comment: Herbrand Models are interpretations using the "syntactic stuff" as domain. This means that a costant $c$ will be interpreted with the "object" $c$ of the domain(see page 105: $c^{I,A}=c^I$).

Comment: Thus, an assignment $A$ will be a function mapping variables into *closed* terms. This means that $v^A$ will be a closed term.

Comment: But if the domain of the int is made of closed term, the result of the assignment $A$ to var $v$ will be the same of subst in place of $v$ the closed term "mapped to" by $A$, i.e. $vA$.

Comment: See also **Def.5.3.8**: for every closed tern $t, t^I=t$.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I think u understand it. Is the proof for $\Phi^{I,A} = (\Phi A)^I$ similar to this proof?